# No se muestra el menu con tkinter

Tags: python, poo, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion contkinter y POO, pero el menu de la parte superior no aparece al iniciar el programa y no se cual es el problema. Gracias por las respuestas

```
from tkinter import *

class Aplicacion:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = Tk()
        self.frame.title("Post")
        self.frame.geometry("350x350")
        self.barraMenu()

    def barraMenu(self):
        self.bar = Menu(self.frame)
        self.file_menu = Menu(self.bar)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label = "Nuevo")
        self.file_menu.add_command(label = "Abrir")
        self.file_menu.add_command(label = "Guardar")
        self.file_menu.add_command(label = "Salir")

        self.bar.add_cascade(menu = self.file_menu, label = "Archivo")


obj = Aplicacion()
obj.frame.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltó añadir la config del menubar, en tu caso sería cambiar

```
obj = Aplicacion()
obj.frame.mainloop()
```

por

```
obj = Aplicacion()
obj.frame.config(menu=obj.bar)
obj.frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudo.